# Removing consecutive duplicates from a list without recursion

Tags: list, recursion, module, duplicates, ocaml

I'm supposed to remove consecutive duplicates from an `int list` without using recursion and using only `List.fold`, `map`, `filter`, `fold_left`, `fold_right`.

I almost got it, but the problem with my code is that it checks if each element equals the 2nd element, and not the next element.

For example if `let z = int list [3;1;4;5;5;1;1]` my code will return `[3;4;5]` and not `[3;1;4;5;1]`. I'm not sure how to change it so `filter` uses a dynamically changing list parameter and not simply the original one (so it doesn't compare each element to the second element (1 in this case) each time):

```
let dupe (ls: int list) : int list =
    List.filter (fun x -> if List.length ls = 0 then true else if x = List.hd (List.tl xs) then false else true) ls
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `List.filter` is this:

```
# List.filter;;
- : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

Notably, the filter function can see only one element of the list at a time. You need to see two consecutive elements to decide what to do, so I'd say `List.filter` won't do the job.

You're going to have to use `map` or one of the folds, I'd say. You can figure out which one(s) will work, with similar reasoning.

(I assume this is the sort of reasoning the assignment is supposed to illustrate. So I'm going to leave it there.)

Answer (score 0):

Without rec

```
 let remove = function
        []    -> []
      | x::tl -> 
         let (_,lxRes)=
           List.fold_left (
            fun (xPrec,lxRes) xCour ->
             if xPrec=xCour then
               (xCour,lxRes)
             else
               (xCour,lxRes@[xCour])
           ) (x+1,[]) (x::tl)
          in
          lxRes
```

Test:

```
# remove  [3;1;4;5;5;1;1];;
- : int list = [3; 1; 4; 5; 1]
# remove [1;1];;
- : int list = [1]
# remove [1;1;1;1;2;2;3;4;5;5];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

With rec (just for information)

```
let rec remove =
function
  | []       -> []
  | x::[]    -> x::[]
  | x::y::tl ->
     if x=y then remove (y::tl)
     else x::remove (y::tl)
```

Comment: Hmm. fold_left is recursive. I would use a reference as mutable variable. Then your code is terribly un-ocamlish, see some style guide. Then you would normally not just give solutions to homework, but hints or half made solutions.

Comment: Suggestion: use `as` to clean this up a bit.  `x::(y::_ as tl) -> if x = y then remove tl else x :: remove tl`

Answer (score 0):

Using just `List.fold_left` can be a little bit more concise than the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33118432/15261315). Of course, this will build up the list in reverse order, so we need to reverse the result.

```
let remove lst =
  List.(
    lst 
    |> fold_left 
      (fun acc x ->
         match acc with 
         | [] -> [x]
         | hd::_ when x = hd -> acc
         | _ -> x::acc)
      []
    |> rev
  )
```

Of course, if you're not allowed to use `List.rev` we can reimplement it easily using `List.fold_left`, `List.cons` and `Fun.flip`.

```
let rev lst = 
  List.fold_left (Fun.flip List.cons) [] lst
```